# What are actual Tesla M60 models used by AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphics-processing-unit, nvidia

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Tesla) that the Tesla M60 has 2x8 GB RAM (whatever it means) and TDP 225–300 W.

I use an EC2 instance (g3s.xlarge) which is supposed to have a Tesla M60. But `nvidia-smi` command says it has 8GB ram and max power limit 150W:

```
> sudo nvidia-smi
Tue Mar 12 00:13:10 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M60           On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   43C    P0    37W / 150W |   7373MiB /  7618MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      6779      C   python                                      7362MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What does it mean? Do I get a 'half' of the card? Is the Tesla M60 actually two cards *stuck* together as the ram specification (2x8) suggests?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the Tesla M60 is [two GPUs stuck together](https://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-m60.html), and each g3s.xlarge or g3.4xlarge instance gets [one](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/g3/) of the two GPUs.

Comment: BTW, what does 's' stand for in 'g3s'? [Other 'g3' machines don't have it.](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#Accelerated_Computing)

Comment: @hans Probably something like "small". That instance type has far less CPU and RAM than the other instance types.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How can it both be small and xlarge at the same time?

Comment: @kasperd You'll have to ask Amazon. I don't understand their naming conventions either.